# PrimeNG(Angular) modules missing in production mode but available in development mode

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have been working on an angular application that utilizes [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/) as the UI component. Initially I was using Angular version 9 with PrimeNG version 8 and I could do my deployments without any problems. So a few months back I updated my PrimeNG version to version 10.0.5-rc1 because there were some new features I wanted.
Development went well but when I try to build my angular application in production mode every component that utilizes any PrimeNG component throws an error. Another thing I have noticed is whenever I try to access a component from a shared module that component is not found because somehow angular can't find the shared module in production mode. Here's a potion of the type of errors thrown.

```
    35   templateUrl: './reservation.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ReservationComponent.
src/app/modules/sales/modules/pos/menus/home/reservations/reservation/reservation.component.html:390:65 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'showCloseIcon' since it isn't a known property of 'p-overlayPanel'.
1. If 'p-overlayPanel' is an Angular component and it has 'showCloseIcon' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-overlayPanel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

390 <p-overlayPanel #deletePaymentOverlayModal [dismissable]="true" [showCloseIcon]="true">

  src/app/modules/sales/modules/pos/menus/home/reservations/reservation/reservation.component.ts:35:16
    35   templateUrl: './reservation.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ReservationComponent.
src/app/modules/shared/pos/reservation-components/create-reservation/create-reservation.component.html:3:1 - error NG8001: 'app-create-edit-reservation' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-create-edit-reservation' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-create-edit-reservation' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

3 <app-create-edit-reservation></app-create-edit-reservation>
```

I have tried to update my PrimeNG version and it's now on the latest version which is 11.0.0-rc1. I have also updated my angular and angular cli version.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you updated your applications angular version to V10?

Comment: it updated to angular version 9.1.12 when I ran the `ng update` command. Even when I ran other commands like `ng update @angular/cli ng update @angluar/core` etc

Comment: I even tried upgrading to angular version 10, then to version 20 but it still doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got angular to build in production mode by changing some variables in the `angular.json` file.

`angular.json` file before refactoring:

```
"namedChunks": false,
"aot": true,
"extractLicenses": true,
"vendorChunk": false,
"buildOptimizer": true,
```

`angular.json` file after refactoring:

```
"namedChunks": false,
"aot": false,
"extractLicenses": true,
"vendorChunk": false,
"buildOptimizer": false,
```

I think there something that I need to correct in the application, maybe get rid of some decapriated libraries etc.